# Entity Framework ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: “'expected CLOB got CHAR”

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, clob, oracle-manageddataaccess

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 6.122.1.0 library is used to access to an Oracle Database from MVC ASP.Net application. It is the latest library version from the NuGet as of November, 14th 2017

```
protected override Expression<Func<MyEntity, object>> getSelector()
{   
    return m => new
    {
        ID = m.ID,
        NAME = m.Name,
        LONGSTRING = "Blah-blah-blah-blah...some thousands characters..." + 
                      m.ID + "blah-blah...blah" 
    };
}

protected override ProblemMethod()
{
    var result = db.MyEntity.Select(getSelector()).ToList();
}
```

There is the problem. That happens, because very long string (some thousands characters) is concatinated into  `LONGSTRING` , and execution of `Select` throw the next exception.

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: "'expected CLOB got CHAR"

My class need to get `Expression` with the `GetSelector()` overriding. 
How to overcome the error or get round it? One way to get round is force EF to execute `Select` on the client. How to do it?

PS: [Same question in Russian.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/741479/22836)

## UPDATE

I should have to present MyEntity

```
 CREATE TABLE MyEntity (ID NUMBER(10), Name VARCHAR2(100));
```

Comment: Maybe you don't really need the "LONGSTRING" property in your 'Selector' ?

Comment: @DanilDev, `getSelector()` must return expression that  prepare to present the data. If it will not do its work,  no one will.

Comment: You are projecting to anonymous type. Please create an object and project into a new SpecialObject that has a property of string{get;set}.

Comment: @Programmer I tried it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168183/entity-framework-ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-clob-got-char#comment81463050_47241328

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to execute the select on the client (i.e. loading ALL MyEntity's and filtering them on the client), you can do:

```
var result = db.MyEntity.ToList().AsQueryable().Select(getSelector()).ToList();
```

The first ToList() loads all entities from the DB. The AsQueryable() allows you to use the Expression function.

I hope this helps.

Cheers,
Nicola

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer, otherwise the question is still open. If you are still looking for other solutions, say so.

Comment: This answer helped me to overcome my problem. But I still don't know real cause what raise the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning an object in the getselector() return an interface (after casting) or a concrete type. This should help entity framework in identifying the appropriate datatype.

Comment: Something like this https://pastebin.com/1CxCnBc3 ? I'll try it, when I'll be able. Do you think EF don't understand LONGSTING is System.String ?

Comment: Yes.. something like that. Oracle manageddataaccess has more problems than documentation in my experience and several features are limited.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help me at all

Comment: Then.. you may need to get all results first and then execute select on them.